# Can you elaborate the following combinatorial proof in details?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinatorial-proofs

I know that the number of permutations is always an integer. But I could't understand how the proof is using the fact $n= 2k$ during the proof. This is the proof.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The proof uses $n=2k$ in setting up the $2k$ varibles to permute. Then the argument is by the multinomial theorem.

Answer (score 0):

The proof shows that *if* $n=2k$ *then* $n!$ is divisible by $2^k$. It uses a combinatorics argument to establish this result (and clearly the argument uses the fact that $n$ is even, for $n$ is $k$ *pairs*), but the end result is not *about* combinations (or permutations) but an elementary result about whole numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You can try another method to prove it. 
Consider $n$ gifts to be distributed among $k$ people such that each person receives $2$ gifts.  (Because we have $n=2k$)

Now for the number of ways. We make groups of 2 gifts each and distribute it among k people. Hence 
$$(\frac{n!}{2!.2!.2!.....[k times]} . \frac{1}{k!}). k! $$

Which on simplifying gives the number of ways as 
$$\frac{n!}{2^k}$$ which is always an integer.

Comment: why multiply by reciprocal of k! and multiply the whole expression by k! again?

Comment: We made k groups of equal sizes(size 2) so the reciprocal of k! (As per the formula of grouping distinct things) And these groups are distributed among k people hence the whole expression is multiplied by k!